# MvxException at Windows Phone by Rio-Binding

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross, monocross

I have some troubles to bind my methods from the ViewModel to the XAML of Windows Phone.
This problem occours not at compiling time self but at the execution in this line of code:

```
System.Windows
      .Application
      .LoadComponent(this, 
                     new System.Uri("/MvvmCross.Phone;component/Views/MenuAuswahlView.xaml"
                                     , System.UriKind.Relative));
```

and the XAML looks like:

```
...
xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:mvx;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.BindingEx.WindowsPhone"
...
<Button mvx:Bi.nd="Command SelectOrder">
...
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I solved the problem because I haven't seen the additional information that the BindingBuilder  was not found.

I added these two line in the setup
    
    var builder = new MvxWindowsBindingBuilder();
                builder.DoRegistration();
    
And now it works!

But don't forget to add the 2 plugins in every project

*FieldBinding

*MethodBinding